# Javascript style type

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to implement it in a way where when the user has visited my page for the first time.

They will have a pop up appearing like a forum message " Hi , you've just visited our forum "
So when the second time the same user visit , the pop up will disappear .

Here's my code I'm working on :

```
var beenherecookie = 'FE44been644';

var beenherebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(beenherecookie);

if (beenherebegin >    -1){

 //Want to implement the code of when user enter first time , "style="display:none;"

else{

function setTimeout("style="display:block;", 60000 * 10); ; //set to 1000 X number of desired delay seconds. So 2 minutes (120 seconds) is 120 X 1000 =   

    120000

WriteCookie("FE44been644","yes");}
```

Here's my HTML code for the style::

```
style="javascript:meh(the function of the style which changes)"
```

So here's the situation :

When the user visit the website for the first time,
The javascript function meh would be style="display:none"

If the user has entered the website previously 
The javascript function meh would be style="display:block"

I need some favors thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can implement the scenario..

declare your meh function

```
var meh = function(){}

if (beenherebegin >    -1){

 meh = function(){
    document.getElementById('popupID').style.display='none';
 }
}

else{
 meh = function(){
    document.getElementById('popupID').style.display='block';
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var isFirstTime = false;
var popupHandler = function(firstTime){
    if(firstTime){
        return "block";
    }
    else{
        return "none";
    }
}

if (beenherebegin >    -1){
    isFirstTime = false;   
}
else{
    isFirstTime = true;
}

document.getElementById('popupID').style.display= popupHandler(isFirstTime);
```

Comment: So the display style i'll just put javascript:meh()?
so when will i turn the isfirsttime to true?
So if cookie which would you recommend?

Comment: I posted the code of native javascript.. 
Yes it's a good approach, editing and appending a better approach (coding oriented)

Comment: I saw your edited code , it's awesome. so I just need to put the style =javascript:meh()? Yes no?

Comment: No. you don't need to do "style= meh()" in html.. 

Just give the popup container the ID i mentioned.. 

eg.. 

<div id="popupID">
   //popup code here
</div>

just check the cookie,run the function as i mentioned in the edit.. It'll work.

PS: please mark the answer as accepted if you liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello,
                   Once you use the cookie profiling to identify if the user has visited before. You can  use document.getElementById.show() and document.getElementById.hide() methods to achieve what you are trying to do. There would be a div element enclosing the popup code, so you can use that. Please tell me if this helps or not. Additionally you can also use jquery methods for show/hide.

Thank You

Comment: Could we like just replace the style function?? Example , if i use document.getelemetbyid.show(), then I would stuff the cookie in their pc..when the pc has the cookie the style = block else none.

Comment: In that case you can follow the above approach. But you need to explicitly access the div element's style using document.getElementById('popupId').style.display = popupHandler(isFirstTime);                                                 By default you would be better to keep the display style in css tag as none, so it gets displayed only when the user is a first tie visitor.